# AGGrid - Angular2 - Object doesn't support property or method 'map'. SystemJS

Tags: angular, systemjs, ag-grid

When trying to simply include the AG-grid Module into a codebase, I'm getting the error "(SystemJS) Object doesn't support property or method 'map'". Is there something else which needs to be included? The AGGrid documentation for Angular2 doesn't seem to mention this. Here's some relevant code snippets. I *think* AG grid / AG Grid 2 is installed correctly - did it from npm install and it's included in the dependencies.

Systemjs.config.js

```
        '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
        '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
        '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js,
        '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
        '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
        '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
        '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
        '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',

        // other libraries
        'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
        'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
        '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': 'node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js',

        // ag libraries
        'ag-grid-ng2' : 'node_modules/ag-grid-ng2',
        'ag-grid' : 'node_modules/ag-grid',
```

...

```
'ag-grid-ng2': {
            defaultExtension: "js"
        },
        'ag-grid': {
            defaultExtension: "js"
        }
```

app.module.ts

```
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import './shared/rxjs-extensions';
import { HomeModule } from './home/home.module';
import { ProjectsModule } from './projects/projects.module';
import { OperationsModule } from './operations/operations.module';
import { AppRoutingModule, routableComponents } from './app-routing.module';
import { SharedModule } from './Shared/shared.module';
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-ng2/main';
import { Constants } from './Services/constants';
import { Configuration } from './Services/configuration';
import { ModalModule } from './Shared/modal/modal.module';
```

...

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    SharedModule,
    FormsModule,
    HomeModule,
    ProjectsModule,
    OperationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ModalModule,
    AgGridModule.withComponents([])],
declarations: [AppComponent, routableComponents],
bootstrap: [AppComponent],
providers: [Constants, Configuration]
```

})

So, what am I missing here??

Comment: I don't know ag-grid but I suggest you take a look at rxJs map operator that usually needs something like `require('rxjs/add/operator/map');`

Comment: Code samples from ag-grid do not have any declaration for map in them.

Comment: Also - did attempt to add the require, but this did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the issue was that I was using an older version of Angular2. By upgrading to 2.4.x. things started to work.